# How to change the order in which RubyMine runs RSpec specs?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine. The order in which RSpec specs run is not random.
I looked in "Edit Configurations", but I couldn't find the option that changes the run order (or a relevant environment variable).
Does anybody knows how to change the configuration to make the specs run in random order?

Answer (score 0):

You were looking in the right place. Run -> Edit Configurations, select the RSpec run configuration you want to change and enter `--order random` in "Runner options".

To make every RSpec run configuration that you create in the future do the same, in Run -> Edit Configurations, select Defaults -> RSpec and make the same change there.